# Get folder names shared on \\XYZ network on windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, nfs

I am trying to get list of all Folders shared on network \\XYZ , I am able to access each folder if I provide folder name like below code.

```
OS.listdir('\\\\XYZ\\folder1')
```

But I want every folder name as I am automating a script to find perticular file across the network.

```
OS.listdir('\\\\XYZ')
```

This give error of path not found.

Comment: Those are shares, not folders.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Ok, so How can I retrieve shares list?